# Is it possible to use the YouTube API in Android to display 360° videos?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to create a native Android app that uses the YouTube Android Player API to access and control YouTube's 360° videos.

The API works but loads the video but at its full view breaking any 360 implementation.

Comment: Google doesn't provide 360 degree control in their own YouTube app. They use Carboard to get 360 degree experience https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/

Answer (score 0):

The Android YouTube Player API didn't work for me, but I was able to get 360 vids working in an Android WebView. I changed the user-agent to match my MacBook:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.86 Safari/537.36`

The full implementation consists of a local HTML file with VideoJS and the YouTube extension, which uses an iframe. The touch/dragging isn't perfect, yet, but it was a step in the right direction.